# запуск кода в отдельном потоке c#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

как запустить этот код в отдельном потоке?

```
WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?owner_id=12&message=" + textBox1.Text + "&access_token=af166ff4349108e2d713");
request.Proxy = new WebProxy("89.36.210.59", 3128);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);    
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(responseFromServer);
var status = json.response.post_id;
```

Comment: Оберните это в метод `private string GetVkPostId()` (`var status = json.response.post_id;` не понятно что должен вернуть метод, но пускай `string`) и запустите это так: `var id = await Task.Run(() => GetVkPostId());`

Comment: @Bulson: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD даже не знаю...

Comment: @Bulson тогда уж лучше юзать `GetResponseAsync()`

Comment: @tym32167 да, можно и так.

Comment: @tym32167 Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/177221. И к тому же, `async`/`await` - это про асинхронность, а не про многопоточность. `await GetResponseAsync` не запускает дополнительный поток (хотя да, основновной поток на время выполнения запроса это разблокирует)

Comment: @PashaPash я так отписал, птому что автор никак не пробовал решить свою проблему, а пришел сюда за готовым кодом - потому я просто дал подсказку, с чего начать. И я в курсе про асинхронность, которая как раз и придумана для того, чтобы не пускать отдельный поток для железовависимых вещей типа сетевых запросов или чтения жестких дисков. У автора проблема - виснет программа. Изменив синхронные запросы на асинхронные автор может решить свою проблему.

Comment: @tym32167 я понимаю, но если вопрос действительно частый - то стоит найти любой подходящий существующий вопрос и закрыть как дубликат :)

Comment: @PashaPash так это надо было сделать ещё на предыдущем вопросе, где я не учааствовал. Да и надо ли мне, как юзеру, искать дубликат, отмечать что то, когда автор мне прямым текстом написал, что считает этот сайт кодогенератором :) Поглядите (если возможно) потертые мои комменты в этом вопросе (кстати, почему потертые?)